# Is this a Mockernut Hickory (Carya tomentosa)?

Tags: identification

These 6 pictures are all from the same small tree. I think it must be a Hickory and probably a Mockernut Hickory (Carya tomentosa). It hasn't borne
flowers yet and therefore no fruit. A chipmunk or squirrel may have carried the fruit there. I'm on the lookout for a parent tree and fruit. It looks like there are a few other smaller trees in the yard like this one. The location is Alexandria, Virginia.

Thank you for your consideration,
Eddie

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Fcf.jpg)

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]